# change colour of table column based on true or false word

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Javascript to populate my table from a database. The table contains two columns that have 'True' and 'False' text. For example Name or Surname will be populated as `True` or `False`. So when 'True' word is detected, that column should be colored with green else with red (`False`). To do this I am using Twitter Bootstrap colors. This is what I have done:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="success">
                <td>True</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="danger">
                <td>False</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is how I built my table:

```
function Table(data) {
    var table = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr>';
    var id= 0;          
    var row = '<tr class=\'staff-row\'id=\'' + data[staff].ID+ '\'</tr>';
    row += '<td>' + data[staff].Name+ '</td>';
    row += '<td>' + data[staff].Surname+ '</td>'

    id++;
    table += row;
    table += '</table></div>';
    $('#DisplayTable').html(table);
$('tr:has(td:contains("True"))').addClass('success');
$('tr:has(td:contains("False"))').addClass('danger');
}
```

Comment: Are you using any data population controls like gridview/datagrid/or any custom generated html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, there are a few options:

[1. Using Filters](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('True') === 0;
}).closest('tr').addClass('success');

$('td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('False') === 0;
}).closest('tr').addClass('danger');
```

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rm3Hz/)</kbd>

---

[2. Using Contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('tr:has(td:contains("True"))').addClass('success');

$('tr:has(td:contains("False"))').addClass('danger');
```

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rm3Hz/1/)</kbd>

Comment: where will i be placing this code. Do i place it before the table is design or after. I have updated my code showing where i place this code but nothing is happening? and the colours are too bright from the look of JFiddle demo, is that's  the colour from bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you data-binding function

```
function Table(data) {
    var table = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr>';
    var id= 0;          
    if(data[staff].Name=="true");
       var color="color:red;";
    else
       var color="color:green;";
    var row = '<tr class=\'staff-row\'id=\'' + data[staff].ID+ '\'</tr>';
    row += "<td style='"+color+"' >" + data[staff].Name+ '</td>';
    row += "<td style='"+color+"' >" + data[staff].Surname+ '</td>'

    id++;
    table += row;
    table += '</table></div>';
    $('#DisplayTable').html(table);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

After creating the table you can do operations on table.Try following code

```
function Table(data) {
        var table = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr>';
        var id= 0;          
            var row = '<tr class=\'staff-row\'id=\'' + data[staff].ID+ '\'</tr>';
            row += '<td>' + data[staff].Name+ '</td>';
            row += '<td>' + data[staff].Surname+ '</td>'

            id++;
            table += row;

        }

        table += '</table></div>';
        $('#DisplayTable').html(table);
 $('#DisplayTable tr td').each(function() {

                                        if ($(this).html() == 'True') {
                                            $(this).addClass('success');

                                        }
                                        else if ($(this).html() == 'False') {
                                           $(this).addClass('danger');
                                        }

                                    });

}
```

Comment: it works but i want to use bootstrap colour which are a bit light this is what i have done for that `$('#showTable tr td').each(function () {if ($(this).html() == 'True') {$('.success');}else if ($(this).html() == 'False') {$('.danger');}});` but its not working?

Comment: where did you add the color in above code.what is the bootstrap colour.it will have some color code right

Comment: it has different colour code: i have shown on above code- (first code) - `<div class="table-responsive">` this is what it starts with

Comment: that is related to div and table.While forming the table it self you can achieve it.

Comment: I did not understand .what you exactly need here .

Comment: yhh it worked i just added the colour code that bootstrap had

Answer (score -1):

This will definitely Solve your problem..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var listItems = $(".table tr td");
    listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
        if ($(this).text() == 'True') {
            $(this).css('background','green');
        } else if ($(this).text() == 'False') {
            $(this).css('background','red');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yunus_Aslam/5Z3B9/1/